# Algorithm or formula for shortest direction to travel between two points relative to a point

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

Given point $(x_0,y_0)$ representing a laser gun, I must find the direction (clockwise or anti-clockwise) to rotate the laser to get it from pointing to point $(x_1,y_1)$ to pointing to point $(x_2,y_2)$ so the spin will be as short as possible. No need to find the angle of the turn.
I believe I need to use polar coordinates somehow.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you don't need to know the angle, does that mean that you can forget about $(x_1,y_1)$?

Comment: No, I still need to know which direction to rotate.

Comment: Compute the vectors $v = (x_1-x_0, y_1-y_0, 0)$ and $w = (x_2-x_0, y_2-y_0, 0)$, and then compute the cross product $v \times w$. The sign of the $z$-coordinate will tell you which direction. Positive means counter-clockwise and negative means clockwise.

Comment: Just to try to clarify: you have a laser in the $xy$-plane at location $(x_0, y_0)$; it's currently pointing towards an object at $(x_1, y_1)$. You want to have it point at $(x_2, y_2)$, and need to know how much to rotate it (and in which direction) to get it there. is that right?

Comment: Thanks @Nick , the answer is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming my interpretation of your question (from the "comments" section) was correct:

Let $u = (x_1 - x_0, y_1 - y_0), v = (y_0 - y_1, x_1 - x_0), w = (x_2 - x_0, y_2 - y_0)$.

Compute
$$
\theta = atan2(w \cdot v, w \cdot u)
$$
and that's the angle you need to rotate.

Here $w \cdot v$ denotes the "dot product" of vectors, and "atan2" is a builtin function in most programming languages. The angle $\theta$ is positive in the direction that moves from the $x$-axis towards the $y$-axis, however these are drawn in your coordinate system.